# If you want to wrap a method that yields, does the wrapper method need to yield also, or will a return suffice?

Tags: python, dictionary, iterator

If I want to wrap a method on a dictionary that is an iterator, is it sufficient to simply return the original function call (which yields), or do I need to propagate the yield in a more explicit way?  For example...

```
def iteritems(self):
    return self.__somedict.iteritems()
```

Or...

```
def iteritems(self):
    for k, v in self.__somedict.iteritems():
        yield k, v
```

Comment: You don't have to, but you can.

Answer (score 3):

In general, you don't need to wrap it with yield, unless you are intending to do some extra work. For instance. if you want to multiply the each value by 2:

```
def times2iteritems(self):
    #note: it is not necessary to use yield here
    return ((k, v*2) for k, v in self.__somedict.iteritems())
```

The difference in these two implementations is that in the first case you return a **reference** to the iterator, while in the second case you do **pipelining**.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using python 3, then you can use `yield from`.
See [this](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0380/).